# no overload for method 'this' takes '1' arguments

Tags: c#

```
string file = "Test.xls";
Workbook workbook = new Workbook();
Worksheet sheet = new Worksheet("First Sheet");
workbook.Worksheets.Add(sheet);
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
sheet.Cells[i][0] = new Cell(""); // error here
workbook.Save(file);
```

Here, I am trying to create an excel file using excel library. But I was getting an error "excel found unclear content. Then I included a for loop to fill the excel sheet with some empty data. But now I am getting the error "no overload for method 'this' takes '1' arguments" on the 6th line in the above code.

I just want to create a new excel sheet using ExcelLibrary in c#.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: 4th line means which line here in the above code?

Comment: The error is clear in my opinion. `Worksheets.Add` method doesn't have an _overload_ takes one parameter with `string` type.

Comment: sheet.Cells[i][0] = new Cell(""); // errors throws on this line

Comment: @user2925479 : Yes it throws error as you are creating an invalid WorkSheet Object -> Worksheet sheet = new Worksheet("First Sheet");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Calvin indicated there are multiple issues with the code.  Here is a working solution:

```
string file = "Test.xls";
Application excel = new Application();
Workbook workbook = excel.Workbooks.Add();
Worksheet sheet = (Worksheet) workbook.Worksheets.Add();
sheet.Name = "First Sheet";
for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
    ((Range)sheet.Cells[i, 1]).Value = "";
workbook.SaveAs(file);
```

Answer (score 1):

`sheet.Cells[i][0] = new Cell("")` You assign cells by a `Range` property not a `new Cell()`

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to refer to MSDN as it's not a straightforward as you would expect or want it to be. VSTO in general stands out from the rest of .NET APIs as being quite unintuitive to work with.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.worksheets.add.aspx

For one thing, you don't call Add passing in the Sheet you think you've just created. Add takes 4 optional parameters but otherwise creates a worksheet and RETURNS the reference to that sheet.

such as in the MSDN example:

```
Excel.Worksheet newWorksheet;
newWorksheet = (Excel.Worksheet)Globals.ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add();
```

To set Cell Value try

```
sheet.Cells[i,1].Value = "";
```

not

```
sheet.Cells[i][0]...
```

Also, advise putting brackets around your for loop for clarity. No benefit in saving two characters.

```
for (int i = 1; i < 100; i++)
{
    sheet.Cells[i,1].Value = ""; // error here
}
workbook.Save(file);
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion Calvin! Now I am getting a run time erro "Can not set value to an empty cell."

Comment: Excel arrays are 1 based not 0 based. So it should be `for (int i=1; i <= 100; i++)` and `sheet.Cells[i, 1].Value = ""`.

Comment: Thanks wdosanjos. Updated the example.

Comment: yes, That makes sense to me. But still I get the same error. I just want to create new excel sheet using ExcelLibrary. But why should we write to excel before creating? However, please help me creating just a new excel sheet in c#. Thanks for your help.

Comment: string filename = "test.xls";
    Workbook workbook = new Workbook();
    Worksheet sheet = new Worksheet("Test");
    workbook.Worksheets.Add(sheet);

    for(int i = 0;i < 100; i++)
          sheet.Cells[i,0] = new Cell("");

    workbook.Save(filename); This works!! but it says excel found unreadable when I try opening the file

Comment: What version of Excel/Visual Studio are you using? You should probably try working with XSLX extension for your filename?

Answer (score 0):

Try assigning the value with

```
sheet.Cells[i][0].Value = "";
```

Comment: Getting same error " no overload for method 'this' takes '1' arguments"